# Error on set argument to Image

Tags: react-native

```
{this.state.items.map((item) => (
  <View style={{height:10, padding:10}}>
    <Image
      style={{flex:1, width: null, height: null, borderRadius:10}}
      source={require(`${item.imagem}`)}
    />
  </View>
  )
)}
```

I cant to set the source > require > argument using a data map

> bundling failed: Error: calls to `require` expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this was found: `require("" + item.codigo)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

You should generate a massive switch-case statement to require what you want or use a babel plugin

You can check more details here:

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391
- https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/52